# Proper usage of properties-maven-plugin to set system properties?

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to use `properties-maven-plugin` to set a system variable that I can retrieve in my Java class.  In my `pom.xml` file I have:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>my.propertyName</name>
                        <value>value</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
           </configuration>
       </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then in my Java class, I have a line:

```
String value = System.getProperty("my.propertyName");
```

but that line of code returns null.

How do I make it work?  :o)

Comment: Where do you need this? During running of your tests?

Comment: No, it's actually during production running of the code.  I need the calling code to provide a properties file to my class so it knows with what parameters to operate.  I would like them to be able to pass me the path in their pom.xml.  I figured that if I used a system variable, I could set a default in my pom, and they could override it in theirs.  I'm open to slicker solutions, if you've got one.  :o)

Comment: If it's during production running of your code maven is out there...A properties file for you production code can be simply put into `src/main/resources` which will be packaged into the resulting jar file...

Comment: I think the common approach here is to set the desired property in `settings.xml`, put placeholder in some property file and read it in the application on start up.

Comment: The plugin will add `my.propertyName` to system properties during the execution of the Maven build. After that, it is gone.

Comment: Why do you need those properties? What is the purpose?

Comment: The calling project tells me which plugin classes it would like me to instantiate to handle incoming data.  They need to be able to edit the properties file at run time so that the system doesn't need to be recompiled to add or update plugins.